# Move details from one table to another one when confirmation is done [sql]

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database-design

I'v got a registeration code which inserts user details into the table that I chose.

The problem is that I added a "confirm code" to the user, so every account is needed to verify his user through his mail. After the confirmation is done, the Column "confirmation" changes to "confirmed". If the user does not verify his account, the confirm code will stay in the "confirmation" Column.

The problem is that I made a table in html, which uses the DB in order to show the active users.

I don't want that the not-confirmed users will appear in the tbale, so I tried to add some conditions:

```
$cu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where uname='$uname' && confirmation='confirmed'");
$cu = mysql_fetch_array($cu);
```

and another one :

```
$select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname='$uname' && confirmation='confirmed'");
```

It's working.. but only half way. I mean, when the not-confirmed user tries to log in, it shows him a blank page. It's ok, cuz I don't want the non-confirmed users will log in.
But... the confirmed users still see the not-cofirmed users in the active users table..

It's like the table doesn't even checks if the user is confirmed or not, it's just shows him either way.

So I thought about a way in which users will move to another table, called "hold", which will consist of all the non-confirmed users. Then, every user who will verify his account, the sql will recognize it and when the confirmation columm is changed to "confirmed", it's going to move the user to the "users" table, so his name will appear in the active user table.

How can I do it? How can I "make" the sql table to auto recongize if the user is confirmed or not, and move him to another table..

or.. if is there any way to "hide" the not-confirmed users from the active users table, it's also fine.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: Whhyyy? Why not have a simple status flag on the users table?

Answer (score 0):

Basically either you need to setup a cron which check if the user is not confirmed then move to hold tabe or write a trigger in mysql whenever any user got confirmed.

Comment: is it possible to set a trigger in mysql whenever any user got confirmed it will move him to the 'users' table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last result and insert after the last result.

See this example:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO tabel_name(col1, col2,col3) values('foo','bar','some'); 
INSERT INTO table_name2(col,col2) SELECT col2,col3 FROM tabel_name 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
");
```